# debug view in Xcode

Tags: xcode

When I debug in Xcode, how can I add the view of picture 1(***main()***) and the view of picture 2(***sort()***) at the same time? Or how can I see the value in array: ***a[10]*** when debug in function: ***sort()***?

picture 1(***main()***):

[image: picture1]

picture 2(***sort()***):

[image]

picture 3(whole picture):

[image]

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>
void swap(int* a, int* b){
    int temp;
    temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}

void sort(int* a, int l, int r){
    int i=0;
    if(l!=r){
        int change=l;
        int move = l+1;
        for(; move<r; move++){
            if(a[move]<a[l]){
                swap(&a[move], &a[++change]);
            }
        }

        swap(&a[l], &a[change]);
        if(change>l){
            sort(a, l, change-1);
        }
        if(change<r){
            sort(a, change+1, r);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int  a[10]={1,2,44,22,2,5,6,0,10,99};
    sort(a, 0, 9);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    int b=2, c=3;
    swap(&b,&c);

    printf("b is %d, c is %d", b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is not possible in a single window. Have you tried opening two windows, one with the first and the other with the second perspective?

Comment: Do you mean I should open Xcode twice?

Comment: You can open another window by double clicking a file from your product.